# What is the nuance difference beween "faire un tour de" and "faire le tour de"

Tags: questions

I'm wondering whether there is a nuance difference between "faire un tour de" and "faire le tour de".
I saw examples for both. E.g. faire le tour du monde, faire un tour d'Europe.
Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*They are the same only for geographical entities,* because the construction also have other interpretation and those can be different for some cases.

- *Faire un tour de* can also mean "have a ride on" (a vehicle, a carousel, a rollercoaster...).
- *Faire le tour de* has the literal meaning "make one's way in circle around".

As such *faire un tour de carousel* and *faire le tour du carousel* mean different thing: the former means riding on it, the later walking around it.

Additionally, you may note in that example a slight different in syntax, in that "faire le tour de" usually requires a definite complements, whereas *faire un tour de* doesn't.